# Rhino: return JSON from within Java

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have the string representation of a JSON-serialized object in Java e.g. `"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":24}"`. How do I parse and return it to the JavaScript context, just the way `JSON.parse(str)` would work in JS? Thanks.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, and the answer was in another question, I would recommend deleting your question.

Comment: questions/answers are slightly different (parse vs. stringify). what to do?

Comment: post your own answer and accept it, then. Since you already posted an answer, you just have to accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest version of Rhino has only four args, and the fourth cannot be null.  To solve this,  you must create a simple class that implements org.mozilla.javascript.Callable:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Callable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;

public class NullCallable implements Callable
{
    @Override
    public Object call(Context context, Scriptable scope, Scriptable holdable, Object[] objects)
    {
        return objects[1];
    }
}
```

You can then call NativeJSON.parse like this:

```
Object result = NativeJSON.parse(context, scope, jsonString, new NullCallable());
```

Comment: Awesome!! Used to struggle against this for a few hours... You saved my day :)) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Awesome!! was searching for a solution since last two weeks.. THANKS ALOT @SoWeLie

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is by calling [org.mozilla.javascript.json.JsonParser.parseValue](http://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/org/mozilla/javascript/json/JsonParser.html#parseValue(java.lang.String)). That is if you don't need to apply a reviver.

More interestingly, `org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON` is built around `org.mozilla.javascript.json.JsonParser.parseValue`. And you can see that here, https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeJSON.java#L110.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: [Access Rhino's native JSON.Stringify from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288669/access-rhinos-native-json-stringify-from-java)

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON;

Object json = NativeJSON.parse(cx, scope, str, null, null);
```

Comment: looks like in the latest version as of now the public version of parse only has 4 args, and the 4th cannot be null. still trying to get it working...

Comment: @antony.trupe, see my answer below.