# Passing json data from javascript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, json

I'm trying to pass json data from javascript to java, like below. The idea is to pass the data to the java code as a javascript object (and not a a string which I know can be done ). I've tried the code below without success - idea was to use NativeJson.stringify to convert from a javascript object to a Java string, however this results in an Undefined instance instead of the expected string. Any idea on this could be achieved much appreciated.

in javascript file "test.js"

```
parser.fct ( {"abc":123,"def":456} )
```

in java

```
//1.binds javascript calls to Java
...
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine...
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("parser", new Parser());
engine.eval("test.js");

//2. in Parser class
public void fct(Object obj){
   Context ctx = Context.enter();
   ScriptableObject scope = ctx.initStandardObjects();
   Object json = NativeJSON.stringify(ctx, scope, obj, null,null);

   //json returned is of type Undefined

}
```

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856154/rhino-return-json-from-within-java

Comment: yes I read the question above - this how I ended up using NativeJSON.stringify... without much luck.

Comment: Checkout the great Jackson JSON Library http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way to use NativeJSON.stringify(). I ended up building the json string "by hand", i.e Iterating on the property ids of the native javascript object and adding these properties to a java Map.

The Map is then transformed into a json object using new JSONObject(map);

link to source code
https://gist.github.com/eleco/c2bc77dca9ecc844a924