# How to get values from a Java HashMap in javascript function using Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-library, rhino

I am using Rhino library to execute JavaScript functions in android. I have a javascript function like,

```
var exucuteJS = function(controlValues) {
var valueSelected = controlValues['country'];
valueSelected = valueSelected.toUpperCase();
 switch (valueSelected) {
    case "INDIA":
        return "IND_HOME";
    case "NEPAL":
        return "NEP_HOME";
    default:
        return "DEF_HOME"
 }
}
```

I am passing a Java HashMap object as parameter, say controlValues to the function executeJS. The problem is , the Rhino cant javascript code, to get the value from the key.

```
var valueSelected = controlValues['country'];
```

the return value is undefined.

it works fine with this line,

```
var valueSelected = controlValues.get('country');
```

but its not valid javascript code.

The same javascript is to be executed both in android and iOS. the above line will not supported in iOS. Please suggest. I am using latest version of Rhino.

Comment: i didnt undestand why downvoted. Requirement will be different for different persons. Down voting without understanding the same is very disgusting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Myself found the answer.

Rather than sending a HashMap to the javascript function, need to send it as a JSONObject. Not like a normal JSONObject's object but as a Object which is in the form of NativeJSON object.

```
Object nativeJsonObject= NativeJSON.parse(rhino,scope,controlValueJsonString,new NullCallable());
```

where,
rhino - Rhino's Context object.
scope - Scriptable's object
controlValueJsonString - JSON string equivalent to the HashMap. (controlValueJsonString = new Gson().toJson(hashMap);)

NullCallable is a class implemented from Callable,(package from rhino's 
org.mozilla.javascript.Callable)

this 'nativeJsonObject' should be passed to javascript function.

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { controlValues };
```

from a JSON object, javascript can get the values as,

```
var valueSelected = controlValues['country'];
```

this is working for me. Really i dont know why down voted to this question.
Admins, please note this issue.

Comment: This is not actually answering the question you asked. This answers how to convert a HashMap to a NativeObject in Java using Rhino. You already answered the question in your question. The way to access a HashMap in a javascript function using Rhino is `controlValues.get('country');`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access data of a complex oject is using its interface. You need to create separate solutions for Android and ios.

The `typeof` operator should help you to switch between these cases.

Comment: My requirement is to run the above mentioned javascript in Android. get() method is purely java. Why its not executing hashmap['key'] method to get  value from hashmap

Comment: because a map is not a js object. The values are not saved in Fields.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this. I have a java HashMap, needs to be sent to javascript funcion.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution where you do not have to implement a NullCallable class is

```
new JsonParser(context, scope).parseValue("{\"this is\":\"JSON\"}");
```

which I found at [Rhino: return JSON from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856154/rhino-return-json-from-within-java)