# Standard JSON parser that comes bundled with Java 6

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to be able to read a JSON string from a file and parse it.

I want to know if the string is a "well formed" JSON. If so, I need to be able to read all the name value pairs.

Is there a JSON library that comes bundled with Java itself?

I would prefer something that comes with the standard Java distribution instead of downloading another external library.

I am using JDK 1.6.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  Most of the JSON parsers for Java are listed at json.org, at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Some people seem to use rhino http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288669/access-rhinos-native-json-stringify-from-java/10837358

Comment: has anybody used json-simple , its a json tool kit from google https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: I have used json-simple.  It seems verbose (compared to Python), but an effective and easy-to-use tool for JSON.

Comment: @davison Only because it may be hosted on Google Code, does not mean it's "from google". Google's JSON parser is Gson, btw.

Comment: @qqilihq thanks for pointing that out. updated my answer so that ppl are not misled. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 5):

Try it approach **without using external library**

http://blog.julienviet.com/2011/12/26/json-to-java-with-jdk6/

EDITED

GitHub is more reliable source of the code from specified link.
https://gist.github.com/vietj/1521692

The key is to use javascript to parse, it can be invoked with:

```
public class JSON2Java {

   private static final ScriptEngine jsonParser;

   static
   {
      try
      {
         String init = read(Tools.class.getResource("json2java.js"));
         ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
         engine.eval(init);
         jsonParser = engine;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         // Unexpected
         throw new AssertionError(e);
      }
   }

   public static Object parseJSON(String json)
   {
      try
      {
         String eval = "new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference(toJava((" + json + ")))";
         AtomicReference ret = (AtomicReference)jsonParser.eval(eval);
         return ret.get();
      }
      catch (ScriptException e)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException("Invalid json", e);
      }
   }
}
```

Javascript part, json2java.js:

```
toJava = function(o) {
  return o == null ? null : o.toJava();
};
Object.prototype.toJava = function() {
  var m = new java.util.HashMap();
  for (var key in this)
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key))
      m.put(key, toJava(this[key]));
  return m;
};
Array.prototype.toJava = function() {
  var l = this.length;
  var a = new java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Object, l);
  for (var i = 0;i < l;i++)
    a[i] = toJava(this[i]);
  return a;
};
String.prototype.toJava = function() {
  return new java.lang.String(this);
};
Boolean.prototype.toJava = function() {
  return java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(this);
};
Number.prototype.toJava = function() {
  return java.lang.Integer(this);
};
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this!! Thanks!!

Comment: This [answer appears to be in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Instead of just linking to an external resource, the relevant material should be posted here, giving proper attribution. This will allow the answer to remain relevant even if the link goes dead in the future.

Comment: @davison Then you can accept my request.:)

Comment: @Thomas Owens i give the link to Git repository.

Comment: Hmm, I pasted the code, but without packages it is useless. Could someone finish this and add proper imports? Also read() method seem to be pseudocode, which could be replaced with actual implementation.

Answer (score -2):

There is the javax.script Api which is built in to 1.6 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html