# NativeJSON.stringify via Rhino Compiler

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, stringify

Rhino relies on a different implementation of the JSON.stringify method : NativeJSON

It can be accessed when calling a script from inside java: [Access Rhino's native JSON.Stringify from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288669/access-rhinos-native-json-stringify-from-java)

I have a script using JSON.stringify. What if I want to compile the script? How do I tell Rhino to invoke the propper method?

Comment: What does `JSON.stringify` have to do with compiling a script?

Comment: JSON.stringify is used inside the script at some point. The script itself runs but not after compilation (inside the Java project).